# PPTP VPN - No internet access though the VPN

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012, internet, pptp

I am very new to the world of windows server

I'm renting a VM in the USA for my web hosting(DC, DNS and Web host role) and I decided that I would install a VPN on it so I could re-route me connections through there and get a US-based IP address since my websites don't get that much traffic.

I followed this guide:
http://www.sysads.co.uk/2013/02/setup-windows-server-2012-vpn-part1/1/

I can successfully connect to the VPN and access my shared folders on the remote machine, etc.

However whenever I connect to the VPN I can no longer access the internet, even if I disable the firewalls on both the server and the client.

When I try to "tracert -d" an external IP address, like google, it times out after the very first hop (Which is the remote server)

What are the steps that I need to perform in order to route my traffic through the VPN?

Comment: Did you enable NAT ?

Comment: It sounds like you may have not gone on to read pages two and three of that guide.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your remote datacenter doesn't route unknown machines (like yours).  You need to be assigned an IP that the router on the other end is willing to route.  This may be NAT or may be something that you work out with the web host.